# how can i make a readonly field when edited

Tags: javascript, vue.js, components, vuejs3

I'm new to vue.js. I want username to be readonly when user wants to edit his record. But it should not be readonly when first registering. Where am I doing wrong, or what should I add ?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to SO! There are lot of syntax errors in your code.

Comment: thank you but this your  answer doesn't work for me, need suggestions thanks again

Comment: Can you please share the fiddle link so that it will be easy to find the root cause and understand the requirement more properly.

Comment: Welcome! It is difficult to answer this question because of the multiple syntax errors.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/mrvayd/fs36w9gc/2/  @RohìtJíndal

Comment: your fiddle code doesn't work at all, also avoid sharing code as images, edit your question and include the actual code snippets after fixing your syntax errors

Comment: Please do not share images of code and/or errors. Instead, copy and paste them here. You should do this since it is impossible to debug screenshots.